# How to select an element efficiently in the same parent div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a loop that produces many divs in my document that resemble the markup below:

```
<div class="row">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <img src="" />
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="myNamedInput">
            <input type="radio" name="myNamedInput">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <a href="#">
    <div>
</div>
```

I wanted to know if there was a better way of accessing the value of the grouped radio input in the div.radio element when someone clicks the link in the div.controls element. This is my jQuery code:

```
$('.controls').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var val = $(this)
        .closest('.row')
        .find('.radio input:radio[name=myNamedInput]')
        .val();
}
```

Is this the fastest way or is there a better way as I feel mine is quite long? I appreciate any help and insight.

Comment: have you tried using `.siblings` - https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: If you **really** wanted the fastest way, then you wouldn't be using jQuery. ;)

Comment: You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002579/how-do-you-select-a-radio-button-in-css

Comment: @coding_idiot, i've used that approach and it seems to work well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the parent div have a id:

```
$('.controls').on('click', function () {
    var val = $("#"+this.parentElement.id + " .radio").val();
}
```

maybe be a solution...

Comment: You are selecting the wrapping `.radio` div, not the radio buttons.

Comment: it's true, @blex!
My fault...

The correct way:
$("#"+this.parentElement.id + " .radio input:radio[name=myNamedInput]").val();

Comment: Thank you. This has definitely put me on the right direction. Issue solved!